# Desktop mirrors Home directory

Tags: home-directory

On Ubuntu 20.04 my desktop has copied ALL files and directories from my Home directory.
If I open a new file and save it in my Home directory it also apears on my desktop.
If I delete a file on my destop it is also deleted from my Home directory.

Is there a setting or solution to this problem. I suspect pilot error but I don't know
what I might have done?

Thanks in advance,
HHS

Answer (score 11):

Just as a test I duplicated your issue by setting my `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` to `$HOME` instead of `$HOME/Desktop` stored in the `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file.  Sure enough I had my whole home directory on my Desktop.

This can be easily fixed.

1. Re-create your home desktop directory from a terminal window by running (If the folder exists it will not create a new one):

   `mkdir -p $HOME/Desktop`
2. Run the following to set the `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` to the correct setting:

   `xdg-user-dirs-update --set DESKTOP $HOME/Desktop`
3. Log out and back in for changes to take effect.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Terrance, your solution worked perfectly. A million thanks. it prompts many questions on areas in Ubuntu/Gnome/etc that I will be trying to answer through further study. Good health to you. HHS

Comment: I think the comment above is odd. NOTHING I've tried works. The bad behavior in NOT on my hard drive because I removed it and the bad behaviour persists. Obviously I can't get to any files to edit with no

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly, thank you.